# QGIS: Intersect two polygons, one line layer as Output

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersect

I have two polygons that intersect, now I want to calculate the length of the outline of the new polygon, but only the outline it shares with one of the input polygons. Is there a way to enter two input polygon layers and receive one, specifically requested output line layer?

Comment: Have a look at this question and its answers: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359279/polygons-from-two-different-shapefiles-that-share-common-border-in-qgis/360453#360453