# How to color only the borders where the polygons are adjacent?

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to only color the borders where the polygons are adjacent?

For example, I want to color the borders in the green circle, but not the ones in the red cirlce.

[image]

Comment: Extract common borders as lines as per this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359279/polygons-from-two-different-shapefiles-that-share-common-border-in-qgis/360453#360453 - then disable drawing of the borders of the polygons, then display the line-layer on top of the polygons.

Comment: Another possibility is to create a polygon with the sea. Then you will need to define a white border